# How to get form data in controller if serialized is used in ajax

Tags: html, ajax, model-view-controller, controller

If I use (#myForm).serialaize() in ajax call on form submission, how the form data can be caught in controller? I mean, what is the representation of form data in controller?

```
 $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
                    $.ajax({
                        url : saveFormUrl, // save url
                        type : 'POST',
                        data : $('#myForm').serialize(),
                        success : function(data) {
                            alert('FormSaved.')
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method of jquery creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. 
And the serialized data will be transferred as string entity through http protocol, the representation of the form data in controller is up to http entity data parser.

Comment: Yes thank you. And form values are reachable from request attributes. need to ensure: name attributes must be assigned in the input tags of form.

Comment: @Backbencher, You do not need to get the values from `Request`. The method you posting to should just contain the model that you using in the view, and the `DefaultModelBinder` will correctly set its properties.

Comment: @StephenMuecke , using path attribute in the input tags of form?

Comment: @Backbencher - I assume you meant the `name` attribute?

Comment: @Backbencher Set the name attribute of input tags, and it will be the name of request attributes.